# Define *def animation[i]* in Python real time plot with ADC serial Arduino

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, serial-port, real-time

I am trying to plot in real time without delay with def animation[i] from matplotlib, but i have problems too realise it.

I have tried normal plot, but it get to slow because the array get to big. I am trying with this website: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/
But i don't really understand how to code def animate[i] with serial input. Sorry still very new to Python

**Classic Arduino AnalogreadInput with SerialOutput without delay**

```
val = analogRead(A0);
Serial.println(val);
```

**Python SerialIn and Plot in Realtime**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import serial
import time

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 25), ylim=(1, 4))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 4800)
val = ser.readline().decode()

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):

    millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    x = str(time.ctime())

    try:
        y = float(val)
    except ValueError:
        ser.readline()

    line.set_data(millis, y)
    return line,
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: It seems to use plt.pause() instead of plt.show(). Are such articles in Japanese helpful? [Arduino で測定したデータを Matplotlib でリアルタイムプロット](https://org-technology.com/posts/matplotlib-realtime-plot.html), [matplotlibでリアルタイム描画](https://qiita.com/hausen6/items/b1b54f7325745ae43e47)

Comment: That seems interesting. I will try it today in the evening

Comment: The code looks fine, except I don't understand the try:/except: clause here. But suppose it does what you want it to, the only problem seems that you only plot one point which cannot be connected by a line to itself. Use `ax.plot([], [], marker="o")` to see the dot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that is my Problem I think. What do I need to code that i get a connected line?

Comment: You need at least two points to form a line